# Why tagged or Marker interfaces are specially treated by JVM

Tags: java, interface

I have a question and I searched, got many answers. I was not sure which is true.
Please can anyone explain. Why tagged interface are treadted specially by JVM?
example:
lets take serializible interfeace which does not have any methods in it, but stil JVM not throwing any compile time exception. How JVM treat such kind of interfaces, what will happen when we implement tagged interfaces.

Comment: why should the jvm throw an exception if an interface has no method? A marker interface allows for type specific implementation - you can do an (instance of) check and perform marker interface type specific customizations. JVM must be doing something similar.

Comment: i donot think this should be as comment, Please can you add it as answer?

Comment: which serializable doenst have any methods can you put your resource? marker interfaces are not usually useful and should be avoided.

Comment: @DarthVader (a) you've never heard of the `Serializable` interface? Which has no methods? (b) A marker interface is as useful as the code it detects it. Your assertion is meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing special about them to the jvm. An interface isn't required to define any methods.  Think of a class implementing an empty interface just as a way of labeling a class as a specific type that you can easily check at runtime with instanceof.

Besides this type information, it can also be used to emphasize high level aspects of a class, or quick identification of classes with specific properties (by both humans and automated tools or IDEs).

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, "marker" interfaces are a distinction made by developers and the libraries they write, not the JVM.

> Why tagged interface are treadted specially by JVM?

It doesn't. An interface with no methods has no special behaviour.  These interfaces are used specially by library designers for particular purposes.

> example: lets take serializible interfeace which doesnot have any methods in it, but stil JVM not throwing any compile time exception.

The later is a hint that the JVM doesn't have awareness of the special behaviour of Serializable interface.  Instead its something the ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputSTream *library* checks for, little more.  Other serialization libraries may or may not do something with this interface. e.g. XStream ignores it.

> How JVM treat such kind of interfaces, what will happen when we implement tagged interfaces.

The only thing special about Serializable the JVM is aware if is that built in array types are Serializable e.g.

```
System.out.println(new byte[0] instanceof Serializable); // is true
```

This only works because the JVM knows this type should be Serializable as its not defined in any class.  This is a special case which doesn't apply to other marker interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any reason why the jvm throw an exception if an interface has no method. 
A marker interface allows for type specific implementation - you can do an (instance of) check and perform marker interface type specific customizations. 
JVM must be doing something similar.

Annotation (post java 5) however is a better alternative to marker interface.

Answer (score 0):

> Why tagged or Marker interfaces are specially treated by JVM

They aren't. I don't know what you mean by 'tagged' but it doesn't make any difference.

> Why tagged interface are treadted specially by JVM?

It isn't.

> example: lets take serializible interfeace which doesnot have any methods in it, but stil JVM not throwing any compile time exception.

There is no such thing as a compile time exception, unless you have a buggy compiler. I've never seen one since 1997. If you are referring to *compilation errors,* they are *printed*, not *thrown*, by the *Java compiler,* not the JVM. If you are asking why no compilation error is printed for an interface that doesn't contain any methods, the reason is that it is legal Java code: check the Java Language Specification.

> How JVM treat such kind of interfaces

The same as any other interface.

> what will happen when we implement tagged interfaces.

The same as for any other interface, although I have no idea what you mean by 'tagged'.

If what you are really asking amid all this confusion is 'how does the `Serializable` interface work'? the answer is that the `ObjectOutputStream` class checks that any object passed to `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` is of a class that implements `Serializable`, via the `instanceof` operator. That's it. No treatment by the compiler or the JVM, just exactly the same sort of code you could write yourself.